# AngularFire watch when only new post arrived

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I would like to notice my web app users when a new post arrived, without a need for them to refresh the page.  I am using firebase and angularfire as the wrapper.

Here is my code:

```
var query = Refs.getDeptRef("IT").orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(25);    
var talks = $firebaseArray(query);
    talks.$watch(function (e) {
                alert('new post arrived');
            });
```

The above code works when new post arrives, however, when I refresh the page (or the first time loading the page), the alert pops-up hundred times!  How do I make it only watch the new posts after the page is loaded??  Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$loaded()`:

> Returns a promise which is resolved when the initial array data has
>   been downloaded from the database. The promise resolves to the
>   $firebaseArray.

Then use `$watch` when the initial data has been retrieved.

For example:

```
var query  = Refs.getDeptRef("IT").orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(25);

var talks = $firebaseArray(query);

talks.$loaded().then(function(initialData) {

  console.log(initialData);

  talks.$watch(function(data) {

    console.log(data);
  });
});
```